# Insert Css with Javascript .click (too late)

Tags: javascript, css

im working on my code, its work's but the action (insert of css) is to late in the actions.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     jQuery("#cal2tozindex").click(function() {
      jQuery("#cal2tozindex").css('z-index','1000');
      jQuery("#cal3tozindex").css('z-index','1');
     });

     jQuery("#cal3tozindex").click(function() {
      jQuery("#cal3tozindex").css('z-index','1000');
      jQuery("#cal2tozindex").css('z-index','1');
     });

});
```

There is the url, you can go on your right in the section, and click on the bleu button with a plane on it named 'vols'.
http://www.voyagesendirect.me/multisites/esther/

**What I want :**

> When you click on the first field : 'date de départ' (cal2tozindex) he
>   should became with a z-index:1000; and the other field : 'date de
>   retour' (cal3tozindex) should be with z-index:1;
>
> Same patern with you click on the second field.

**My actual problem :**

The insert of css is to late, the javascript put the css, after you click on a date, and not when you click on the field first. I really need that the code work's on the first click (on the field) and not on the second one (on a date).

Thanks to everybody to helping me solving this problem !

Comment: never excuse for your english. It is good ;)

Comment: try adding/removing css classes instead.

Comment: Can you explain your problem in plain English, not in terms of JavaScript/CSS. This will help us provide a better solution.

Comment: Solved ! I need to target the button and the field, and not the container !

Comment: @Peter - if you solved it by yourself you can always post an answer and accept it after 2 days. It will help others in case they search for a similar problems.

Comment: alright, i'll do it in few hours: 'Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 3 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
    jQuery("#date_dep_calFLT").focus(function() {
    jQuery("#cal2tozindex").css('z-index','1000');
    jQuery("#cal3tozindex").css('z-index','1');
});
jQuery("#bt-cal_FLT").click(function() {
    jQuery("#cal2tozindex").css('z-index','1000');
    jQuery("#cal3tozindex").css('z-index','1');
});

jQuery("#date_ret_calFLT").focus(function() {
    jQuery("#cal3tozindex").css('z-index','1000');
    jQuery("#cal2tozindex").css('z-index','1');
});

jQuery("#bt-cal_FLT_ret").click(function() {
    jQuery("#cal3tozindex").css('z-index','1000');
    jQuery("#cal2tozindex").css('z-index','1');
});
```

});